# Text to speech in php

Tags: php, jquery, text-to-speech

I have a project in php and jquery. 
The last thing I need to do is that when a user clicks a button, the name of user that is a text, the pc convert the text name into sound and is played to the pc speaker.
There are any class or plugin that could help to do this?
Thanks

Comment: This is not a job for PHP. Look for a command-line tool to do this, and call it from PHP using `exec()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a plugin from jquery that solves my problem.

http://www.jtalkplugin.com/

thanks all for response

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

http://www.masnun.me/2009/12/14/googles-text-to-speech-api-a-php-wrapper-class.html

Here is its implementation with demo.

URL: http://stuffthatspins.com/tag/php-tts/

Demo: http://stuffthatspins.com/stuff/php-TTS/

Comment: Good one, but using this he would need to save the audio data to the PC and still exec some player that will play the audio file... +1

Comment: See the last link. you can play it.

Comment: Yep, but does not work with FF yet... And surely won't work with IE >= 8.